# Emailing a HTML form with PHP

Tags: php, html, css, forms, email

New guy here so excuse any errors I've probably already made but I think I'm good so far haha. Anyway, I'm trying to design a website right now and am using a template, a bit of HTML knowledge and some small knowledge of CSS! So far its going all well (I think) but I'm having issues with a 'Contact us' kind of form. I have the layout and setup but have no idea how to set up the PHP or where to put it or anything! Any help would be highly appreciated! Here's the HTML I have for the form at the moment with image included. Thanks!

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="field half first">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="senderName" id="name" />
    </div>
    <div class="field half">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="senderEmail" id="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="senderMessage" rows="5"> </textarea>
    </div>
    <ul class="actions">
        <li><a href="" class="button submit">Send Message</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

[Picture of Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8G4S.png)

EDIT: Thanks for the help guys and input knew I'd do something wrong on my first time haha! I guess its time to learn PHP then? :) Always a first time for everything thanks everyone! :P

Comment: You're basically asking, "How do I do web development with PHP?"  That's *far* too broad for a Stack Overflow question.  Start with pretty much any introductory tutorial on PHP.

Comment: Yeap, you should narrow down your question. For instance, try installing PHP (after reading some) and ask a question about a specific problem you face, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to start by watching the thenewboston tutorials which are great!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCUV3iv9xOs&list=PL442FA2C127377F07

Answer (score 0):

1. Learn what is "composer": https://getcomposer.org/
2. Learn what is GitHub: https://github.com/
3. Explore some popular PHP frameworks and start learning one of them.
4. Make some small test project using selected framework (for example blog).
5. You would be very embarrassing for a question, and you will realize that it was impossible to answer it.
6. Profit =)